# Calling an Oracle procedure within a package from a different schema?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedures

I've created the following package with 3 procedures:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PQ_PaqueteIntegrantes
AS 
PROCEDURE INTEG_INSERCIONES(paIdIntegrante IN CreadorTablas.INTEGRANTES.ID_INTEGRANTE%TYPE 
                           ,paNombre IN CreadorTablas.INTEGRANTES.NOMBRE%TYPE
                           ,paApellidoPaterno IN CreadorTablas.INTEGRANTES.APELLIDO_PATERNO%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INTEG_MODIFICACIONES(paIdIntegrante IN OUT CreadorTablas.INTEGRANTES.ID_INTEGRANTE%TYPE 
                              ,paNombre IN OUT CreadorTablas.INTEGRANTES.NOMBRE%TYPE
                         ,paApellidoPaterno IN OUT CreadorTablas.INTEGRANTES.APELLIDO_PATERNO%TYPE);

PROCEDURE INTEG_ELIMINCACIONES( 
               paIdIntegrante    IN OE.EJEMPLO_TRANSAC_CLASE.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE
                                ,paMjeDescError OUT VARCHAR2
                                ,paCodeError    OUT NUMBER);             
END PQ_PaqueteIntegrantes;
```

I created those procedures with a user called **Admin_proyectos**. The first procedures makes "Inserts", the second one "Updates", and the last one "Deletes", all of them working on a table called **Integrantes**, that table comes from another user called **CreadorTablas**.
My intention is to create another user called **Admin**, who will have the responsibility to do those things, using the procedures from this package, of course. I've tried doing an PL/SQL block, but it didn't work, neither with an EXEC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ADMIN_PROYECTOS.PQ_PaqueteIntegrantes TO Admin
```

Then, you can call the procedures in this package with `Admin` user as

```
BEGIN
ADMIN_PROYECTOS.PQ_PaqueteIntegrantes.INTEG_INSERCIONES(paIdIntegrante, paNombre, paNombre);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **execute immediate** statement:

```
 l_sql_stmt := 'alter table ' || p_table_name || ' drop partition ' || i.PARTITION_NAME || ';';
            dbms_output.put_line( l_sql_stmt );
            execute immediate l_sql_stmt;
```